# Compiler error message error:expected ')' before '*' token. Error with my constructor

Tags: c++, ros

I keep getting the following compiler error

> In file included from
>   /home/armon/Development/groovy_workspace/sandbox/smart_wheelchair/trunk/smart_wheelchair/state_machine_planner/src/BasicControllerState.cpp:1:0:
>   /home/armon/Development/groovy_workspace/sandbox/smart_wheelchair/trunk/smart_wheelchair/state_machine_planner/include/state_machine_planner/BasicControllerState.h:38:49:
>   error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
>   /home/armon/Development/groovy_workspace/sandbox/smart_wheelchair/trunk/smart_wheelchair/state_machine_planner/src/BasicControllerState.cpp:4:44:
>   error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’
>   token   In file included from
>   /home/armon/Development/groovy_workspace/sandbox/smart_wheelchair/trunk/smart_wheelchair/state_machine_planner/include/state_machine_planner/StateMachinePlanner.h:16:0,
>                      from /home/armon/Development/groovy_workspace/sandbox/smart_wheelchair/trunk/smart_wheelchair/state_machine_planner/src/ControllerNode.cpp:4:
>   /home/armon/Development/groovy_workspace/sandbox/smart_wheelchair/trunk/smart_wheelchair/state_machine_planner/include/state_machine_planner/BasicControllerState.h:38:49:
>   error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token   make[3]:* 
>   [CMakeFiles/state_machine_planner.dir/src/BasicControllerState.cpp.o]
>   Error 1   make[3]: * Waiting for unfinished jobs....   In file
>   included from
>   /home/armon/Development/groovy_workspace/sandbox/smart_wheelchair/trunk/smart_wheelchair/state_machine_planner/include/state_machine_planner/StateMachinePlanner.h:16:0,
>                      from /home/armon/Development/groovy_workspace/sandbox/smart_wheelchair/trunk/smart_wheelchair/state_machine_planner/src/StateMachinePlanner.cpp:1:
>   /home/armon/Development/groovy_workspace/sandbox/smart_wheelchair/trunk/smart_wheelchair/state_machine_planner/include/state_machine_planner/BasicControllerState.h:38:49:
>   error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
>   /home/armon/Development/groovy_workspace/sandbox/smart_wheelchair/trunk/smart_wheelchair/state_machine_planner/src/StateMachinePlanner.cpp:
>   In constructor
>   ‘state_machine_planner::StateMachinePlanner::StateMachinePlanner()’:
>   /home/armon/Development/groovy_workspace/sandbox/smart_wheelchair/trunk/smart_wheelchair/state_machine_planner/src/StateMachinePlanner.cpp:9:30:
>   error: no match for call to
>   ‘(state_machine_planner::BasicControllerState)
>   (costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS*&)’

BasicControllerState is a member of StateMachinePlanner

here is the code,

BasicControllerState.h (relevant piece):

```
class BasicControllerState {
                public:
                        BasicControllerState(){}
                        BasicControllerState(costmap_2d::costmap2DROS* costmap_ros);
```

BasicControllerState.cpp:

```
#include <state_machine_planner/BasicControllerState.h>

namespace state_machine_planner {
        BasicControllerState::BasicControllerState(costmap_2d::costmap2DROS* costmap_ros) {
                //init trajectory parameters specific to what state the child class     represents  

                //init sim_time_ and sim_granularity_
                //init sample space limits
                //init best_score_thresh_

                obstacle_dist_cost_gain_ = 0.1;
                heading_diff_cost_gain_ = 0.0;
                linear_vel_cost_gain_ = 0.0;
                omega_cost_gain_ = 0.0;

                num_of_linvel_samples_ = 20;
                num_of_angvel_smaples_ = 40;

                costmap_ros_ = costmap_ros;
                costmap_ros_->getCostmapCopy(costmap_);
                robot_footprint_ = costmap_ros_->getRobotFootprint();
                world_model_ = new base_local_planner::CostmapModel(costmap_);
        }
```

StateMachinePlanner.h:

```
class StateMachinePlanner
        {
                public:
                        StateMachinePlanner();
                        void init(int latency_command_queue_size, vel_params_struct vps, time_params_struct tps);
                        void setKey(key_command_t key);
                        geometry_msgs::Twist computeVelocityCommands();
                private:
                        std::deque<Eigen::Vector2f> latency_command_queue_;
                        int latency_command_queue_size_;
                        vel_params_struct velocity_parameters_;
                        time_params_struct time_parameters_;
                        navigation_state_t current_state_;
                        key_command_t key_command_;
                        tf::TransformListener* tf_;
                        costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros_;
                        costmap_2d::Costmap2D costmap_;

                        BasicControllerState forward_state_;
```

StateMachinePlanner.cpp (where I instantiate it):

```
namespace state_machine_planner {

        StateMachinePlanner::StateMachinePlanner() : tf_(NULL), costmap_ros_(NULL) {
                tf_ = new tf::TransformListener(ros::Duration(10));
                costmap_ros_ = new costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS("costmap",*tf_);
                costmap_ros_->getCostmapCopy(costmap_);
                forward_state_(costmap_ros_);
        }
```

Forgive me, I know it may seem trivial, but I was hoping to find some c++ wizard to bail me out. Have spent far too long on this one problem.

Comment: Did you include the relevant headers?

Comment: Case sensitivity: `costmap_2d::costmap2DROS` != `costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS`.

Comment: Yes, I do have all the relevant headers

Comment: Casey, you are a beautiful human being, and I wish you all the joys life has to offer

Answer (score 0):

costmap_2d::costmap2DROS* needs a forward declaration or you need to include the header file where it is defined. Because it is a pointer, a forward declarion is better. So before the class definition do this:

```
namespace costmap_2d{
  class costmap2DROS;
}
```